# MS Graph SignInActivity Attribute missing?

Tags: api, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I'm quite confused by the documentation that's uploaded to the MS site,

I'm working on auditing inactive users within Azure AD, yet when I follow the below two links I cannot for the life of me find the attribute "signinactivity" with my Graph API reponses:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-manage-inactive-user-accounts
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/signinactivity?view=graph-rest-beta

Any help with this? Has the feature been taken out?

Apologies for my ignorance, but I'm confused that I've followed the documentation instructions yet the results are not there when I execute.

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Body $postParams
$token = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $response.access_token  -AsPlainText -Force
$query = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Authentication Bearer -Token  $token -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=displayName,userPrincipalName,signInActivity"
```

Comment: Have you tried testing in [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge)? Make sure you have the Azure AD Premium P1/P2 license. Check for all the users if the property is missing or not.

Comment: Yep, the graph explorer doesn't show the call.
And can confirm I've got P2 licenses assigned for all.

Comment: Have you seen any signinactivity property for all user objects?

Comment: It exists and working for me... Adding the result below, as i can't append the output/picture here.

Comment: Just to isolate the issue further, see if you can repro the issue with Graph explorer with same Graph API call and for working/inactive users to isolate the issue further.

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma - This was one element of the issue. I was able to figure out that I needed to escape the "$" in my "select" expression.

However, the first user returned did not have a signinactivity attribute, and when outputting the results it would ignore everyone else's signinactivity.

I overcame the issue with the following code:
`query.value | Where-Object { $_.signInActivity -ne $null } | Select-Object displayName, userPrincipalName, id, @{Name='signInActivity';Expression={$_.signInActivity.lastSignInDateTime}} | Export-Csv -Path "textextract.csv" -NoType`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears your `$select` expression *is ignored* since PowerShell tries to expand `$` into a variable. A `$` prefix needs to be escaped, in PowerShell with "`" (backward apostrophe/grave) character:

```
$requestUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?`$select=displayName,userPrincipalName,signInActivity"
$query = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Authentication Bearer -Token  $token -Uri $requestUrl
```

**Option 2**

Alternately you could enclose string expression in single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"` (in that case `$` prefix does not need to be escaped):

```
$requestUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=displayName,userPrincipalName,signInActivity'
```

**Option 3**

Since [on the beta endpoint, the `$` prefix is optional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters) instead of `$select`  you can specify `select`:

```
$requestUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?select=displayName,userPrincipalName,signInActivity"
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim - I was able to figure this out before reading your answer but this was in fact the issue with how I was calling the API.

Comment: Interestingly, the first user returned has no signinactivity and as a result, all of the returned users ignore the "signinactivity" column when outputting results, I have worked around this by performing a "Where-Object" and "Select-Object" to filter results

Comment: Would love to see your code for the where-object @Burgtaro as I'm struggling with this myself